# Function to determine how many object attributes are blank with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, attributes, instance-variables

I have a model 'Employee' with ten attributes (i.e. name, email, DOB, etc). For a particular instance of an Employee object that has just been created, I would like to use a function to determine how many of its attributes are blank. E.g.

```
# In this employee instance, the values for the three attributes shown are all blank,
# thus the function would return '3'

employee"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "dob"=>"", # etc }
```

Any help with the best way to go about doing this is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know if it's the best way, but this would work:

```
employee.attributes.count { |key, value| value.blank? }
```